# Primefaces drop event is not invoked

Tags: jsf, primefaces, drag-and-drop

I am using drag and drop with datagrid.
I expose for your my code.
I am using primefaces 4.0 and have followed the exemple detailed in documentation.
The problem is that the drop function dropQuery is not invoked.

```
    <div id="columnwrap"> <p:droppable for="report" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource="availablequeries" onDrop="handleDrop" >
        <p:ajax listener="#{dragQueryMB.dropQuery}"  update="dropArea availablequeries"/>
    </p:droppable>

        <div id="column1">
            <p:fieldset id="report" legend="Report" >
                <p:outputPanel id="dropArea">
                    <h:outputText value="drop here" rendered="#{not empty dragQueryMB.addedQueries}" style="font-size:16px;" />

                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="column2">

        <p:fieldset id="queryfield" legend="Available Queries" >
            <p:commandLink value="add new Query"  action="createQuery?faces-redirect=true" style="position: right" ></p:commandLink>
            <p:dataGrid id="availablequeries" value="#{dragQueryMB.queryList}" var="query" columns="1">
                <p:column>

                <p:panel id="pnl" header="#{query.queryTitle}" style="text-align:center">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">


                        <h:outputText value="#{query.description}" />


                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>

                </p:column>
                <p:draggable for="pnl" revert="true" handle=".ui-panel-titlebar" stack=".ui-panel"/>


            </p:dataGrid>
        </p:fieldset>
    </div>
```

Method dropQuery:

```
public void dropQuery(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {    
    Query query = ((Query) ddEvent.getData());     
    addedQueries.add(query);     
    queryList.remove(query);    
}
```

Comment: can you post your method `dropQuery`?

Comment: I added my  dropQuery method

Comment: Altough it is an outdated question: Probably you are missing a surrounding <h:form></h:form>.